# Allowing null and asserting it's not - flutter framework

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable

I came across this file https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/widget_span.dart and on line 98, I find this strange that the list declared as parameter :

```dart
List<PlaceholderDimensions>? dimensions
```

is set as nullable. Yet, 2 lines further, it seems to be rejected by :

```dart
assert(dimensions != null);
```

I am thinking that it could be a mistake, but it's Google, so I prefer asking.

Anyone has an idea of why this could be useful for dart / flutter?

Comment: If you initalize the list by ...dimensions = []; the list itself cant be null. If you like to check for null values inside the list you would probably need to loop trough it by the index

Comment: ```List<PlaceholderDimensions?> dimensions```
This a non-nullable list with potentially nullable elements in dart.

Comment: The parameter is to a function that overrides a base class function.  I'm not familiar with this particular widget, but I could guess that the base class interface *allows* for a null argument, but the derived class perhaps can guarantee that the argument will never be null in practice.

Answer (score 0):

@jamesdlin - you were right.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/inline_span.dart is a superclass.

On line 220, it's defining the build function and this other widget is overriding it with more constraints.

Thanks !